# Form data store in CSV with IP: Undefined error

Tags: php, forms, csv, undefined

I am trying to get email, country and IP address from visitor and store into CSV and also will send email to the site owner.

I am not much familiar but I got most thing works but not able to rid off Undefined error for `$cvsData .= "\"$email\",\"$ip\"".PHP_EOL;` line...

`Error Message: Notice: Undefined index: ip_address in`

Here is my code

```
<?php

// this is to store form into csv file
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {   
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


        if(empty($email))
        {
            echo "ERROR MESSAGE";
            die;
        }
        $cvsData .= "\"$email\",\"$ip\"".PHP_EOL;
        $fp = fopen("emails.csv", "a");

        if($fp)
        {
            fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file
            fclose($fp); // Close the file
            echo "<h3>Thank you! we will inform you.....</h3>";
        }    

    }

// this is to send email to site owner

    // Contact subject
    $email ="$email";
    // Enter your email address
    $to ='myemail@site.com';

    $subject ='site Email Submited';

    $send_email=mail($to,$email,$subject);

    // Check, if message sent to your email
    // display message "We've recived your information"
    if($send_email){
        echo "Email address is sent to the department.";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }

?>
```

Form has only one field name="email" and submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is not in your code (that you pasted in) because `ip_address` is not mentioned.